# Los datos que envio a la base llegan vacíos

Tags: php, html, mysql, post

Cada vez que hago clic me figura que los datos se enviaron, en phPmyAdmin me aparece esto: "MySQL ha devuelto un conjunto de valores vacío (es decir: cero columnas). (La consulta tardó 0,0006 segundos.)" y bueno, llega vacío. A que le estoy errando? porfavor necesito una mano

HTML

```
<?php
            include("registrar.php"); 
            ?>

            <div id="documento">
              <h1>&bull;Documento&bull;</h1>
              <img id="x" src="imagenes/cruzar.png">
              <div class="underline">
              </div>
              <form action="#" method="post" id="contact_form" target="pp">
                <div class="name">
                <label for="name"></label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre del grupo" name="name" id="name_input" required>
              </div>
             <div class="message">
               <label for="message"></label>
                <textarea name="content" placeholder="Escribe tu opinión aca" id="message_input" cols="30" rows="5" required></textarea>
              </div>
              <div class="submit">
                <input type="submit" name="register" value="Enviar documento" id="register" />
              </div>
            </form>
            <iframe name="pp" style="position:absolute; top:-1500px;"></iframe>
          </div>
```

CONEXION

```
<?php  
    
    $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","isla");

  

?>
```

PHP  REGISTRO

```
include('con_db.php');



if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
    if (strlen($_POST['name']) >= 1 && strlen($_POST['content']) >= 1 )  {
        $name = trim($_POST['name']);
        $content = $_POST['content'];
        $date = date("y/m/d");
        $consulta = "INSERT INTO `users`(`nombre`, `texto`, `fecha`) VALUES ('$name','$content','$date')";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
        

    } 
    
    }
    


?>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
let mandarDatosYCambio = document.getElementById('register').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    if(envio==0){        
    document.getElementById('name_input').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('alertaSegundaReunion').style.display = 'block';
    envio = envio + 1;
    } 

    
});
```

(esto no hace falta que lo lean, es solo para que me deje preguntar)

estaba pensando en poner lo siguiente, como para ejecutar la función de PHP en el caso de si es interrumpida por el js.

```
function enviarDatos(){
let result ="<?php registro(); ?>"
}
```

y agregarle la función a php.

Comment: Lo siento, las imágenes con código no ayudan a darte ninguna respuesta. Debes agregar el código como texto para que podamos trabajar con el para mirar de reproducir tu error o para darte una respuesta sin que suponga un sobreesfuerzo por nuestra parte. Puedes pulsar sobre el enlace [edit] que aparece a pie de tu pregunta para eliminarlas y poner el código en modo texto. Léete [ask], [tour] y [example] para aprender cómo funciona este sitio, gracias.

Comment: ahí lo cambie, gracias por avisar

Comment: Podrías hacer un echo, yendo por el else de if (isset($_POST['register'])) { ... } else { echo $_POST['name'];} y ver que te retorna?

Comment: me muestra bien el resultado de lo que escribo y mando, también probé el textarea.

Comment: Depura la consulta agregando un `echo $consulta;` despues de la línea de la consulta: `$consulta = "INSERT INTO ...`  y mira si salen todos los datos correctamente, y luego vas y lo copias y pegas en tu phpMyAdmin, en la pestaña SQL, y lo ejecutas a ver si funciona.  Si funciona entonces el problema es tu conexión a la base de datos. Si no funciona entonces te aparecerá un error que podrás analizar mejor para ver que falla.

Comment: no me figura nada, me parece que el problema viene de otro lado, estoy usando js, para cuando le doy clic al botón enviar me abra un div. puede ser que me interfiere eso?

Comment: No lo se, no has puesto el javascript en la pregunta. Imagino que haces una petición ajax. Puedes editar de nuevo tu pregunta y agregar el javascript para que podamos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: ahí lo edite, me parece que me vas a cagar a pedos, tengo la excusa de que todavía soy JR, tenedme paciencia. PD: (El enviar = enviar + 1; es para porque al terminar determinado tiempo se tendría que ejecutar el mismo código, así cancelo enviarlo 2 veces)

Comment: Es cosa mia, o primero intentas hacer la consulta, y luego abres la conexión a la base de datos?

Comment: nono, la conexión la tengo incluida arriba del registro, solo que en la pregunta lo puse al reves

Comment: @Lucianogimenez No somos adivinos... si no pones las cosas tal como las tienes, vamos a encontrar problemas que no existen como que estás usando $conexion antes de declararlo. No podemos ver todo tu proyecto así que por favor, edita la pregunta y pon todo el código en el orden correcto. Además de todo esto... no puedes poner php en javascript puesto que JS se ejecuta en el cliente y PHP en el servidor, es decir, tu función enviarDatos no insertará nada al usarla, si no al declararla!

Comment: okey, ahí lo cambié, perdón no me di cuenta hasta que lo mencionó masterguru. No tenia ni idea que no se complementaban, tendría que usar ajax si o si? gracias por la ayuda a todos!

Comment: ¿Has "printeado" el valor que llevan las variables cuando llegan a PHP o a JavaScript?
Puede ser que no se esté enviando nada, por tanto, el error está en el formulario o puede ser que no se esté haciendo correctamente la conexión en PHP a la base de datos. ¿Has capturado la conexión por si hay error al realizarla?

Comment: como andas Juan? gracias por la ayuda. Si lo hice, me imprime todo bien cuando no uso JS. tendria que usar ajax para esto pero todavía no lo conozco, así que me falta estudiar jaja. gracias, igual si hay alguna forma de meter JS para que se ejecute bien el PHP estaría salvado

Comment: Correcto. No hay otra forma más que utilizar AJAX. Ánimo con el estudio!